# Measure Theory on integrals

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Is it true that if $f\in L^1 (X,\mu)$ then 
$$\int_E |f| d\mu +\int_{E^c} |f| d\mu = \int_X |f| d\mu?$$

Comment: Yes, it is true.

Comment: Could you give a brief explanation why it is true?

Comment: Because $E\cap E^c=\emptyset$ and $E\cup E^c=X$.

Comment: Can we argument this by the obvious fact that it holds for the characteristic functions and simple functions and therefore for all positive functions?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\int_X|f|=\int_X\chi_E|f|+\int_X\chi_{E^c}|f|.$$